# Sum Range Based On Values List

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet with a list of VIP customer IDs.

I then have another sheet with column A as all customer IDs and column B as revenue.

I'd like to sum the revenue in column B when the customer ID is one of the matches from the VIP list.

I know I could probably do a lookup in a new column to see if they match, and then do a sumif, but I want to do this as efficiently as possible as there are 100,000s of customer IDs and the list automatically increases over time.

Answer (score 0):

You will look at [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) as example:

```
=SUMIF(RevenueSheet!A2:A,VIPsheet!A2,RevenueSheet!B2:B)

=SUMIF(range, criteria, sumrange)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying a formula like this, on your VIP sheet:

```
=QUERY(
  FILTER(SHEET2!A1:B,
    COUNTIF(A4:A,SHEET2!A1:A)),
  "SELECT COL1,SUM(COL2) GROUP BY COL1 ORDER BY COL1 LABEL COL1 'VIPs', SUM(COL2) 'SumRevenue'",0)
```

The cust ID (or name) and revenue data is on Sheet2, columns A and B, with a header row.

Here is a sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15jZtOK0oXkSAw06iZ-aQQHxRKxqGJL0ryVwZr56LV74/edit?usp=sharing

There are other ways of doing this, but I would think that the filter is pretty efficient at reducing the column of data to include only the VIP data, and then the query sums the revenue data, grouped by each VIP (name or ID).  Various sorting options could be applied.

Let me know if this works for you.

[image]